# Replace expression like +{user}100 using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like this:

```
Test+${user}100,very important text
```

I am trying to remove the part `+${user}100`

Why my code isn't working?

```
noSpecialSigns = noSpecialSigns.replaceAll("\\+$\\{user}\\d","");
```

Comment: Use a  quantifier `+` for the digits and escape the dollar sign `\\+\\$\\{user}\\d+`

Comment: If your string is always separated by a comma, you could just do `.+,` for the regex.

Comment: This regex `\+\$\{user\}\d+` should match just `+${user}100`. You can test your regex on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

- You need to escape the `$` sign
- The `\d` will only match a single digit. You need to add a `+` to match a series of digits:

```java
noSpecialSigns = noSpecialSigns.replaceAll("\\+\\$\\{user}\\d+","");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape all the plus `+` and parenthesis `{}`, because they are a part of the regex syntax, your regex should be [`\+\$\{user\}\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/X5IDCw/1) :

```
noSpecialSigns = noSpecialSigns.replaceAll("\\+\\$\\{user\\}\\d+", "");
```